# aws elasticsearch signed delete request returns 403 forbidden (using apache httpclient)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-delete, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm getting an http `403 forbidden` error trying to delete an `aws elasticsearch` index via the java [Jest(v6.3)](https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest) elasticsearch client (which delegates the http calls to [apache httpclient(v4.5.2)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)   I know my permissions are setup correctly in AWS as I'm able to successfully use postman(with the help of AWS Signature authorization helper).  however, with `apache httpclient`, when I issue the `DELETE /{myIndexName}` I receive the following error:

```
    The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
    Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. 
Consult the service documentation for details.
```

I'm signing the `aws` request by configuring the `apache httpclient` with an interceptor that signs the request.(The code below is for a `Spring Framework @Configuration` class that wires up the java `Jest` client and underlying apache httpclient) but I imagine if I used apache httpclient directly I'd experience the same issue.

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private CredentialsProviderFactoryBean awsCredentialsProvider;

    @Bean
    public JestClient awsJestClient(@Value("${elasticsearch.url}") String connectionUrl) throws Exception {
        com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider provider = awsCredentialsProvider.getObject();

        final com.google.common.base.Supplier<LocalDateTime> clock = () -> LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        final vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigner awsSigner = new vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigner(provider, "us-east-1", "es", clock);
        final vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigningRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigningRequestInterceptor(awsSigner);


        final JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory() {
            @Override
            protected HttpClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder builder) {
                builder.addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptor);
                return builder;
            }
            @Override
            protected HttpAsyncClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
                builder.addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptor);
                return builder;
            }
        };

        factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
                   .Builder(connectionUrl)
                   .connTimeout(60000)
                   .multiThreaded(true)
                   .build());

        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

Since it's working with postman it points to the a signing error but I'm at a loss to where the discrepancy is occurring.  The configuration above works for all `apache httpclient` requests besides http DELETE requests.

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of research I found some clues that pointed to the possibility that the presence of the `Content-Length` (length=0) in request issued to aws were causing the signature mismatch.  I'm guessing that the signature done via the client interceptor was not factoring in the `Content-Length` header but since we were sending the `Content-Length` header to the aws server it was factoring it in and thus causing the signature mismatch.  I believe this to be the case because I added an additional interceptor(before the AWS signing interceptor) that explicitly removes the `Content-Length` header for `DELETE` requests and the request goes through successfully. (i.e. I'm able to delete the index). Updated code below:

```
@Configuration
public class ElasticSearchConfiguration {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConfiguration.class);
    @Autowired
    private CredentialsProviderFactoryBean awsCredentialsProvider;


    @Bean
    public JestClient awsJestClient(@Value("${elasticsearch.url}") String connectionUrl) throws Exception {
        com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider provider = awsCredentialsProvider.getObject();

        final com.google.common.base.Supplier<LocalDateTime> clock = () -> LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        final vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigner awsSigner = new vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigner(provider, "us-east-1", "es", clock);
        final vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigningRequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new vc.inreach.aws.request.AWSSigningRequestInterceptor(awsSigner);

        final HttpRequestInterceptor removeDeleteMethodContentLengthHeaderRequestInterceptor = (request, context) ->  {
            if(request.getRequestLine().getMethod().equals("DELETE")) {
                log.warn("intercepted aws es DELETE request, will remove 'Content-Length' header as it's presence invalidates the signature check on AWS' end");
                request.removeHeaders("Content-Length");
            }
        };

        final JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory() {
            @Override
            protected HttpClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpClientBuilder builder) {
                builder.addInterceptorLast(removeDeleteMethodContentLengthHeaderRequestInterceptor);
                builder.addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptor);
                return builder;
            }
            @Override
            protected HttpAsyncClientBuilder configureHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder builder) {
                builder.addInterceptorLast(removeDeleteMethodContentLengthHeaderRequestInterceptor);
                builder.addInterceptorLast(requestInterceptor);
                return builder;
            }
        };

        factory.setHttpClientConfig(new HttpClientConfig
                .Builder(connectionUrl)
                .connTimeout(60000)
                .multiThreaded(true)
                .build());

        return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```